# Programmatically detect which SQL Server is principal,which is the mirror?

Tags: sql-server, scripting, powershell, sqlcmd

I am looking for a way to programmatically query which SQL server is serving as the principal SQL server and which one is the mirror in a pair. Does anyone know if this is possible via PowerShell (SQLPS) or CMD (SQLCMD)? If so, how can I go about querying this info?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

I don't have an instance handy to test with, but I think you should be able to query [sys.database_mirroring_witnesses](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174391.aspx) (SQL Server 2005 or later) using SQLCMD to get at the information you are looking for.

**EDIT**
Thanks to @Remus for the great comment. The appropriate place to look is in `sys.database_mirroring`.

Comment: You should use `sys.database_mirroring` though, which contains the database state/role (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178655.aspx). `sys.database_mirror_witnesses` contains info about the mirroring witnesses.